# Python - Set first and last words of permutations

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm looking to create a list of permutations but set the first and last words always the same.

```
import itertools
 
list = ['cow', 'sheep', 'rooster', 'ram', 'donkey', 'horse', 'goat', 'pig']
for x in range(1, len(list) + 1):
    for i in itertools.permutations(list, x):
        print ("".join(i))
```

So, for instance, how would I make the first word always be cow and the last word always be pig?

Comment: Another pro-tip - don't use `list` as a variable name. Use something like `name_list` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all possible outcomes, you need an outer loop to change the `r` parameter:

```
from itertools import permutations

l = ['cow', 'sheep', 'rooster', 'ram', 'donkey', 'horse', 'goat', 'pig']
first, *others, last = l
for r in range(1, len(others)+1):
    for p in permutations(others, r):
        print(first, *p, last, sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
cow, sheep, pig
cow, rooster, pig
cow, ram, pig
cow, donkey, pig
cow, horse, pig
cow, goat, pig
cow, sheep, rooster, pig
cow, sheep, ram, pig
cow, sheep, donkey, pig
cow, sheep, horse, pig
...
cow, goat, horse, ram, rooster, sheep, donkey, pig
cow, goat, horse, ram, rooster, donkey, sheep, pig
cow, goat, horse, ram, donkey, sheep, rooster, pig
cow, goat, horse, ram, donkey, rooster, sheep, pig
cow, goat, horse, donkey, sheep, rooster, ram, pig
cow, goat, horse, donkey, sheep, ram, rooster, pig
cow, goat, horse, donkey, rooster, sheep, ram, pig
cow, goat, horse, donkey, rooster, ram, sheep, pig
cow, goat, horse, donkey, ram, sheep, rooster, pig
cow, goat, horse, donkey, ram, rooster, sheep, pig
```